# Is there any way to use two consoles for simultaneous play on the same TV by using Dualplay?

Tags: xbox-system-link, dualplay

Are there any devices that can merge two HDMI device signals into one 3D-like signal so that I can display them using [Dualplay](http://www.lg.com/us/tv-audio-video/discoverlgtvs/dualplay)?

Normally, Dualplay requires a game (and console) that supports this feature to be played on just one console. I would like to use two consoles on the same TV using the Dualplay feature and play something over Live or system link.

In other words:  I want to play two separate games on the same TV at the same time, but not be able to see each other's game.

*For those who are unfamiliar:  [Dualplay](http://www.lg.com/us/tv-audio-video/discoverlgtvs/dualplay) is television feature (developed by LG) that utilizes the 3D layering features of certain televisions to project two separate channels of information that are then viewable with 3D glasses which filter one of the two channels.  This allows you to play a dual player game, but at full screen instead of the traditional split-screen style of play where each player can only see their own information.*

Comment: I've edited your post to make it a bit clearer what you're asking.  The link now goes to LG's official site about Dualplay.  And, I've added an explanation of what dualplay is.  I believe this might help you get an answer.

Comment: No problem.  Someone nominated this for a closing vote as off-topic.  I think it had a lot to do with the way it was worded initially.  I hope you find an answer, but honestly, I would doubt there is a device out there that does this (*yet*).

Comment: This question has also been discussed [here](http://www.avsforum.com/forum/194-3d-tech-talk/1850074-two-hdmi-sources-full-res-3d-signal.html) but without any solutions as of today.

Comment: Is it possible by using [3Dfury products](http://www.hdfury.com/product-category/allproducts/3dfury/) maybe?

Comment: The main problem for this to work is the sound, which would be a mess from 2 different sources.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau That is were the greatness of headphones come in. There are headphones you can buy that channel the sound

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I also think sound would not be the problem. With two Xbox consoles, for example, each player could just plug headphones into his/her controller and receive his/her individual sound directly from his/her Xbox. The TV could simply be muted (if receiving sound at all).

Comment: you are right, but what if the device can output the two different sound to two different sound outputs and only forward the merged video inputs to one HDMI output without sound?

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I just remembered about the world of Picture in Picture!

All you need is an HDMI Switch, Matrix, Video Processor or any PiP compatible HDMI device.

I found [this one](http://www.ambery.com/4quvipiviprr.html) that does what you're looking for, although it's RCA only, so no HD. I also found HDMIs one on a famous asian wholesale website, but I won't link to it since I have no way to tell if it would work.

The only thing you need to make sure is that the Picture in Picture can be stretched side-by-side or top-to-bottom. From the product page:

[image: PiP modes]

Only modes 15 and 16 would work for your use case.

---

While I have never heard of such a device, there are absolutely ways to achieve what you are looking for.

3D pictures are sent to your TV/Projector in a framepacked way (usually at least), meaning both screens are squished on either a full frame image, or combined into one that is twice as large. (I wrote [a blog post](http://stuff.mousta.ch/post/116892326603) about this with pictures a while ago).

To get your frames together, You'll probably need some kind of video mixers. Analog ones exist for VJing and live broadcast purposes, but we're looking at $400 and up. You can also do the same thing with your computer, by having two capture cards and a live video mixing software. If you're on a Mac I suggest VDMX, on a PC I beleive Resolume should do the trick. The problem with the hardware way will be latency.

Essentially, what you want to do is get a single video feed that looks like this:

[image: Crazy Good Mockup]

Here, I chose Framepacked Side-by-Side Left to Right, which is the most common way to send 3D images.

Your next problem will be the glasses. If your glasses are **Active** (as in, they need power and talk to the source), you'll need to either mod them yourself ([Here's someone who did it](http://3dvision-blog.com/3139-modifying-the-3d-vision-glasses-to-show-2d-left-or-right-frame-only/)) to shut both eyes at the same time, or find 2D-3D glasses that correspond to your source (major brands have those).

If you have **Passive** glasses (the ones in most theaters, really rare at home) , just break two pairs and exchange opposite lenses. You can also [buy thoses](http://www.2d-glasses.com/) apparently.

[image: How you might look]

I'm actually very surprised no device exist for this purpose. But this is definitely doable, as long as you don't mind a bit of lag and destroying two pairs of glasses. If you tell me more about the hardware you have at hand I can provide a more detailed guide.

EDIT: Bulk list of things to consider:

- 3D TVs can *usually* take any HDMI input and use it as a 3D source, but some will require licensed 3D hardware. You can try beforehand by connecting a non-3D device and enabling the 3D options in your TV's settings. If it doesn't work, you probably won't be able to do what you're trying.
- SBS 3D (the one I used in the mockup) is the standard, however Top/Bottom might work better since a game would probably require more horizontal definition.
- If you're modding **passive** glasses, be sure to keep the lens' orientation the same. If the glasses are fairly round, you can simply rotate one lens 90°.
- Not all video mixers offer transformation. Be sure to read manuals.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question at all. Your answer is about 3D images. The question is about layering two different video streams on the same screen, so a user with one set of glasses would only see stream A, a user with the other set of glasses would only see stream B, and a user with no glasses would presumably see an unholy mash of both.

Comment: Hey Dallium, thanks for the heads up, I forgot to precise that the Picture in Picture should be "Side By Side" (and not exactly PiP), therefore making a 3D image in which has a different HDMI input for each eye. I'll update my answer now.

Comment: Wouldn't this solution make it so one player saw their screen on one half of the screen with the other half being blank?

Comment: Nope! The idea is to map each player's screen on one half of the final one (see the Halo mockup), then telling the TV it is a 3D image. The TV will split it in half, stretch each half back to their original size, and show the left/right halfs to the left/right eye respectively. Since we're changing the glasses, each player only sees one eye, and therefore one screen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Moustach, I agree that it is just a matter of hardware. Do you think the following setup would work? Connect an HDMI to SDI-HD converter to each console (e.g. https://www.aja.com/en/products/mini-converters/ha5). Then, connect one SDI-HD output from each converter to the input of an SDI to HDMI 3D converter (e.g. https://www.aja.com/en/products/mini-converters/hi5-3d). Then connect the 3D HDMI output of that converter to the 3D TV and use the dual play glasses to see the image of one console only. Don't know if that would create additional latency, however.

Comment: Would it work? Most certainely. However I do not know anough about SDI to assure you it's worth spending more than $1k  for such a setup. I'll keep looking and tell you if I find a cheaper solution.